# Angularjs Why my filter always get all the array of objects?

Tags: html, angularjs

I made a custom filter in angularjs, but in the filter function always gets the full array of objects even if i selected just one, i took a look to the console log

> Size of array : 4
>
> Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object ]

the select code:

```
<select ng-model="query" data-placeholder="Buscar..." multiple class="control-group html-multi-chosen-select" multiple="multiple" chosen >
                            <optgroup ng-repeat="pueblo in pueblos[0].estados | orderBy:'nombre'" label={{pueblo.nombre}}>
                                <option value=""> </option>
                                <option ng-repeat="localidad in pueblo.localidades | orderBy:'nombre'" value={{localidad.nombre}}>
                                    {{localidad.nombre}}</option>
                            </optgroup>
                        </select>
```

the custom filter is inside a table row:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="pueblo in pueblos[0].estados | busqueda:query | orderBy:'nombre' ">
     <td>
          <p>{{pueblo.nombre}}</p>
          <p data-ng-repeat="localidad in pueblo.localidades| busqueda:query | orderBy:'nombre'">
          {{localidad.nombre}}</p>
    
     </td>
```

and the code of the filter:

```
App.filter('busqueda', function(){
             
  return function(input){
    var out = []; 

    if(!angular.isUndefined(input)){
     console.log("size of array: "+ input.length);
       console.log(input);

      for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++){
           
             for(var j=0;j<input[i].length;j++){
             
             console.log(input[i].nombre);
             out.push(input[i].localidades[j].nombre);

             }
           
       }
      return out;      
    }

     console.log(out);
     console.log("*****************");
     return null;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ze2rv6ZvlABzHHt7J2K7?p=preview).  I simplified a bit, but this should explain what you are trying to do.

---

Steps:

1. Remove `multiple="multiple"` from the `select` tag, you only need the one.
2. Change the value of the repeated option elements to `value={{localidad}}` and add the localidades id to the localidad.  You will need both numbers for your two filters to work.
3. Change your table row to:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="pueblo in pueblos[0].estados | filter:filterEstados | orderBy:'nombre' ">
    <td>
        <p>{{pueblo2.nombre}}</p>
        <p data-ng-repeat="localidad in pueblo.localidades | filter:filterLocalidad | orderBy:'nombre'">{{localidad.nombre}}</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

4. Add the following to your scope initialization (assumes localidades id is in the `localidadesNombre` property):

```
$scope.filterEstados = function(value, index, array) {
    if(!$scope.query || $scope.query.length <= 0 || !value){
        return false;
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.query.length; i++)
    {
        var currentVal = angular.fromJson($scope.query[i]);

        if(currentVal.localidadesNombre === value.nombre){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
$scope.filterLocalidad = function(value, index, array) {
    if(!$scope.query || $scope.query.length <= 0 || !value){
        return false;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.query.length; i++)
    {
        var currentVal = angular.fromJson($scope.query[i]);

        if(currentVal.nombre === value.nombre){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

---

I had trouble getting your custom filter to work in Plunker, but it should be easy to adapt this code once you have it implemented.

Comment: yes, but the input is supposed to bring only the selected objects?

Comment: You will need to add code which indicates what is selected for me to help you further.  Currently this code only converts a 2 dimensional array to a 1 dimensional array.

Comment: there is in the html code, is binded with the **ng-model="query"**

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, I thought the filter was suppose to be removing elements.  I will look at it more when I have time tonight.  Your expectation that query should only have the selected items is correct.  I will build a plunker or fiddle and let you know.

Comment: Thank you, this kinda  works, still i have some bugs, first if an object **estado**  has more than one nested object, and i just select one, it will bring all the nested objects to the table. i will update the post later after some tests.also why two filters? it can't be done  with only one filter?

Comment: @B.J.A.A. You have to filter the group separate from the option.  If you select 11, 12, and 44 in my plunker, you should get two rows in the table (for estados 1 and 4).  The first row should have three paragraphs (1 for the estados number and two for localidad 11 and 12).  The second row should have two paragraphs (1 for the estados and one for localidad 44).  If you still need help, create a new plunker from mine showing the issue, create a new question, and add a comment to this question with the link to the new.  I will look at it when I have time.